# Bash: split list of files into different files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have several files in a directory like:

```
data1.dat
data2.dat
....
data24678.dat
```

To run another code, I need to have a text file with the names of the files but I need to split in 50 files per text file, like:
File1.txt :

```
/PATH/OF/FILE/data1.data
/PATH/OF/FILE/data2.data
/PATH/OF/FILE/data3.data
......
/PATH/OF/FILE/data50.data
```

File2.txt :

```
/PATH/OF/FILE/data51.data
/PATH/OF/FILE/data52.data
/PATH/OF/FILE/data53.data
......
/PATH/OF/FILE/data100.data
```

any idea?? I was trying like:

```
ls -1 | xargs -n 50 >> File1.txt
```

but I don't know who to select each "item" in the xargs command.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -1 | split --lines=10
```

puts the files in the same directory. This can be avoided by

```
ls -1 | (cd /where/ever; split --lines=10)
```

or for a different file name:

```
ls -1 | split --lines=10 /dev/stdin /path/to/splitfile.
```

Comment: THANKS!!! and how can I change the name of the text files?

Comment: @Alejandro I added that but that information was already in Graeme's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (uses GNU `split` which is default on most Linux distros):

```
ls |
  sed "s:^:$(pwd)/:" |
  split -dl 50 --additional-suffix=.txt - /path/to/dest/File
```

Comment: I got this error: split: unrecognized option `--additional-suffix=.txt'

Comment: @Alejandro If it is not supported, just remove that option. The effect will just be that the files don't have the `.txt` extension.

Comment: The `-d` may not be supported on some systems also, this gives numbered files instead of `aa`, `ab`, etc. The rest is POSIX though.